# Specificity - inferring or adding "all" in someone's statement

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, objects

I see this issue come up very frequently in arguments, for example. Person 1 might say: `Trees have leaves` or `Christians attend church.`

Person 2 will then step in and retort that "not *all* trees have leaves!" or "not *all* Christians attend church, you dummy!".

Obviously this isn't a very useful discussion as Person 1 was generalizing and did not mean to claim that *all* trees have leaves. (I think you can only make an absolute claim about *all* trees if it's implicit in the definition of a tree or follows logically from it - a tautology, and not very useful. But generalizations and approximations are very useful - indeed necessary - for humans. Science, for example, is based off of statistics, not logic. Our whole system of naming "things" in the world is based off of generalizations and arbitrary delineations.)

So my question is: Is it correct to insert the word "all" into someone's statement like that? How about "some"? Is there a default that should be used? Is it context-dependent?

Comment: Yes, it is valid.  Speakers need to be careful to qualify with, “most Christians” or “most trees” if they don’t intend ***all***

Comment: it may be obvious to Person 1 that they were generalizing but how is Person 2 supposed to know this? They will hear the statement and think: “that’s not right, I wonder if he was was just generalizing or if he really thinks they all have leaves.”

Comment: In order to find out Person 2 then says,” Not ***all*** trees have leaves.” and sees how Person 1 responds.

Comment: I don't think it would be sensible to criticise 'Dogs have four legs' unless the context actually demanded this. Pragmatics often informs interpretation (and thus phraseology).

Comment: Is this really specific to English? I suspect it's common to most languages, and reflects the way humans think in generalities, rather than absolutes. Or are other language users generally more careful about when they use their translations of "all", "most", "some", etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Generalizations are perfectly valid. In fact, if you look closely, *they are all we have*. What is a **tree**? Isn't every single one of them different? Yet we have *generalized* them into the concept of a "tree" which is ambiguous and imperfectly defined and delineated.

Given that every single tree is different, can we really say anything about *all trees*? There is only thing we can say - a tautology: we can say that *all trees are trees!* But clearly this does not possess any practical meaning.

So our language is imperfect. Meaning jumps across the gap from reality into our conceptualization of reality. Then it jumps across the gap from our conceptualization to our peer's. But guess what? We still use language, and it's still incredibly useful for us. We just have to embrace it with all its imperfections and generalizations.

If Person 2 for some reason refuses to accept generalizations, then they can grind the conversation to a halt very easily. Anything you say about anything they can respond with "that's not *always* true - there are exceptions - and therefore you're wrong!"

Usually in these situations it's not just stupidity on the part of Person 2, but a blatant lack of good will. Person 2 probably doesn't want to understand Person 1, they're just acting obtuse, being belligerent, or trying to mislead a third party.

So, should we automatically insert *all* or *some* or *many*? I think we should make an assumption based on the context if it's obvious. Often times it will be. If it's not, and if it's an important point in the discussion, then by all means ask for clarification (in good will).

Keep in mind that even if it is *all*, unless the context of the discussion is within a logical framework, or unless they're telling you a definition, they are probably generalizing and you could probably come up with some exceptions to "prove them wrong". By why would you want to unless you're trying to be obtuse?